# Saving Apache log files for more that 14 days

Tags: apache2

It seems that apache saves/compresses logs for 14 days. I see these log files now

```
# ls
access.log        access.log.12.gz  access.log.3.gz  access.log.7.gz  error.log.1      error.log.13.gz  error.log.4.gz  error.log.8.gz
access.log.1      access.log.13.gz  access.log.4.gz  access.log.8.gz  error.log.10.gz  error.log.14.gz  error.log.5.gz  error.log.9.gz
access.log.10.gz  access.log.14.gz  access.log.5.gz  access.log.9.gz  error.log.11.gz  error.log.2.gz   error.log.6.gz  other_vhosts_access.log
access.log.11.gz  access.log.2.gz   access.log.6.gz  error.log        error.log.12.gz  error.log.3.gz   error.log.7.gz  other_vhosts_access.log.1
```

Is there any way to increase the number of days?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. The file `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` contains:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 14
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
                    run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
            fi; \
    endscript
```

}

So, you could simply `sudoedit /etc/logrotate.d/apache2` and change `rotate 14` to `rotate 999`, or whatever you like.

Read `man logrotate`.

Comment: Thanks I saw it. Should I restart something to take place?

Comment: @mahmood No need to restart anything since logrotate is not a deamon [see this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116136/how-to-make-log-rotate-change-take-effect).